# RxAndroid: Create Simple Hot Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm creating an Observable which emits Integers when subscribed to. My implementation right now is set up so the act of subscribing to it triggers the generation from the start, as follows:

```
private Observable createObservable() {
    return Observable.create (
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> sub) {

                for (int i = 1; i < MAX_PROGRESS + 1; i++) {
                    sub.onNext(i);
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
                sub.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

My understanding is this is a cold Observable. I want the sequence to be generated irrespective of any subscribers, and when a subscriber does subscribe, want them to receive the values which happen to be current at the time of the subsciption. IOW, turn this into a hot Observable. I'd rather not subclass Observable because that ties it into a concrete Integer, whereas in practice the actual type will vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject<T>`.  If you aren't familiar with `rx.subjects.Subject`s the most general way that I can think to describe them is that they break the continuity of subscriptions between point A and B. How is does it is by being both an `Observer<T>`; Can accept `onNext()`s from multiple sources (**WARNING**: external thread safety required). On the other side a subject is also an `Observable<T>` so multiple `Observer<T>`s can subscribe and `onNext()`s coming in will be multicast out to each downstream `Observer<T>`.

If your code looked like

```
Observable<T> src = ...;
Subscriber<T> dst;
src.subscribe(dst);
```

The way to use the BehaviorSubject is

```
Observable<T> src = ...;
BehaviorSubject<T> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(defaultValue);
src.subscribe(subject);
```

subscribe immediately to the source and the subject will take is as fast as it is dished out.  The BehaviorSubject only keeps the more recent value and drops the defaultValue & all previous values.

```
// safe to do multiple times.
Subscriber<T> dst;
subject.subscribe(dst);
```

On subscribe `dst` receives the most recent value from the `src` (or the `defaultValue`) immediately upon subscribing and then all subsequent values until `dst` unsubscribes.

**WARNING**: Subjects have a tendency to overused so be sure you need one.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this more, with Subjects, and ended up writing a medium story on it: https://medium.com/@carl.whalley/the-reactive-revolution-rxandroid-and-how-it-finally-clicked-for-me-part-1-of-2-a35122a6091e#.tfyb97spm

Answer (score 0):

In your example you using "Observable.create" each time  calling function. "Hot" subscription save some instance from Observable. Also you need use some Rx methods (cache(), retry())  In code it's look like:

```
    public Observable<Bitmap> mObservable;
    Subscriber<Bitmap> mSubscriber;
    Subscription mSubscription;
    Bitmap loadedBitmap;

....

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            loadedBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("LoadedBitmap");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(loadedBitmap);
        }
        else {
            runNewObservable();
        }
        runSubscribe();
        return mainView;
    }

....

    private void runNewObservable () {
        mObservable =
                Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Bitmap> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext(new LoadingImage().loadImageFrom(imageURL));
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .cache();

    }



    private void runNewSubscribe () {
        mSubscriber = new Subscriber<Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() { }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) { }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Bitmap bitmap) {
                loadedBitmap = bitmap;
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSubscription = mObservable.subscribe(mSubscriber);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("LoadedBitmap", loadedBitmap);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

....
```

As you can see. I use just mSubscription.subscribe() and mSubscription.unsubscribe() and create Observable only when saveInstanceState is null.

Comment: I'm also using the same technique to preserve the Observable across the Activity creations, but I don't see the difference there between the way you create your Observable and the way I do. I want my Observable to just continue irrespective of subscribers.

Comment: Use example above with Simple data (Observable.just to return value every one second), and try Subscriber in item with new Observable and using Subscription (Check if Observable is created). And you undersand the difference. In first way  load 10 value  and rotate device. Loading start againg from zero. In second way, shen you load 10 items and rotate device, loading next items starting from previous value (from 10).